# WatchKit adding images to cache callback

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm working on a photo sharing app with an extension for Apple Watch.

Therefore I need to display the user's images similar to Instagram etc.

Question:
Is there any way to find the progress of `addCachedImageWithData:name:` ?

Is it blocking? (I don't really think so, but maybe I'm waiting for something else..)

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] addCachedImageWithData:imageData name:imageName];
```

I would like to only show the interface to the user after the images are actually loaded (or my interface will be empty...)

Answer (score 1):

`addCachedImageWithData:name:` seems to call `[SPCompanionAssetCache addImageToPermanentCache:withName:]` that access with mutual exclusion and totally synchronusly using the `objc_sync_enter/objc_sync_exit` procedure to send the request to the Apple Watch.

I guess that the return value is the connection status. In your context you can assume that the caching procedure is synchronous.

TL;DR: No, you can't get the progress about the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

The docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/addCachedImage:name:) don't mention it specifically but in my experience it returns YES or NO immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussions in the developer forums, this call is not blocking. However, you can use `setImageNamed:` immediately after making the call, and WatchKit will correctly set the image after it's actually transferred. So, as Nicolò mentioned, you can use this as if it's synchronous.

There is no method to determine the progress of the transfer, though you can discover the size of the cached image in bytes with the `cachedImages` property on `WKInterfaceDevice`.

Finally, you are allowed to cache images on a background thread. More image tips here that you might find useful: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118580394879/watchkit-image-tips